# Why is the likelihood a product of pdf terms $f(\theta; x_1, x_2, ...)$

Tags: likelihood

Before anyone says this has been answered elsewhere I don't think it has.

The likelihood is given by:

$$ L(θ;x_1,\cdots, x_n) = \prod^n_i f(x_i\mid\theta)$$

where $f$ is the probability density function for a continuous function or probability mass function if discrete.

For a discrete probability distribution, the individual $f$ terms are probabilities so I understand the need to form a product.

For a continuous probability distribution such as the normal distribution, the probability is the area, not the height. Why can we multiply the heights for a pdf when computing the likelihood since the height itself isn't a probability?

Comment: @whuber : I think you're quite mistaken in calling this a duplicate. Look closely at the two questions.

Comment: @Michael I did (of course!).  Could you be more specific about how they differ?

Comment: @whuber : The other one is asking how to define the likelihood function (not the density) for a mixture of continuous and discrete distributions. This one is not really about likelihood functions at all. The poster seems to think it is, but it's really about joint densities. The poster is familiar with the identity $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ when $A,B$ are independent events, and it's obvious how to apply that to a joint probability mass function, since the values of that function actually are probabilities. But he values of a density function of a continuous random$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$variable are not probabilities, so that simple identity on probabilities of independent events cannot be applied. So the question is why one then proceeds in the same way in that case, just doing the multiplication.

Comment: @whuber : $\qquad \uparrow\qquad$ The question ought to get edited to show that it's not really about a function of $\theta$ at all, and indeed any mention of $\theta$ is superfluous.

Comment: @whuber : BOTH this question and that other question are expressed in an overly complicated way.

Comment: @whuber : If both were re-written to make them appear as simple as they really are, then they would no longer look similar.

Comment: @whuber : Contrast my answer to this question with Xi'an's answer to the other question. They're about quite different things. My answer below would fail as an answer to that other question; it doesn't address the matter at all.

Comment: @Michael I see that the answers differ, but--despite the OP's responses to your answer--I remain unconvinced that these two threads are at all different.  This question in its current form explicitly focuses on the likelihood and can readily be interpreted as wondering why it is valid to multiply probability *densities* to compute it.  That's how I interpret the duplicate, too.  I'm certainly open to changing my mind if the question were edited to rule out different interpretations.

Comment: @whuber : But the o.p. says he understands why it works in the discrete case but wonders why it still works in the continuous case. It's answerable without writing about a function of $\theta$ at all. There's nothing about how to define the likelihood function as a function of $\theta.$ The other question is about what function of $\theta$ should be used when there's a mixture of discrete and continuous distributions. Independence of observations, or the fact that there's more than one observation, is irrelevant to that.

Comment: @whuber : Notice that Xi'an's posted answer doesn't say anything about multiplying densities.

Comment: @whuber : ....whereas here that is the heart of the matter.

Comment: @Michael, I don't see those issues as being irrelevant, but rather as *generalizing* the current question.  It comes down to whether one perceives this question as being about *multiplying* densities or about *treating densities as if they were probabilities* in forming likelihoods.

Comment: @whuber : One question can be viewed like this: Suppose $\Pr(X=0) = 1/\theta$ and the probability distribution of $X$ given that $X\ne 0$ is uniform on the interval $(0,\theta).$ How shall we define the function $\theta\mapsto L(\theta),$ the likelihood, a function of the parameter $\theta$ with $X$ fixed at the value that was actually observed. There's nothing in that about the joint density of independent random variables; all that is inessential to the question. The other asks$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: @whuber : $\ldots\,$why it is the case that if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are densities of independent continuously distributed random variables, the function $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto f_1(x_1)\cdots f_n(x_n)$ is the joint density. There's nothing about a function of a parameter that parameterizes a family of distributions. The questions appear very similar because of superficial similarities between the clumsy ways in which they were expressed.

Comment: You claim that both questions were clumsily written, I don't understand that. Can you expand on that?

Comment: @rhody : They included too much information. If they had been written in a way similar to the way I sketched them in the two comments above, they would have been clearer. In particular, as far as I understand your question, the parameter $\theta$ plays no role.

Comment: I wrote the likelihood function as a function of the parameters because that's how it was defined in the textbooks I've read. I could have left out the parameter. I suppose and defined the likelihood as $L (x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \prod f (x_i)$. I can reedit the question if this is a better way of expressing it. I'm not a hardcore statistician and I think you have more experience in this that I have.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302198  (following @MichaelHardy's interpretation of the question)

Comment: @rhody : You could have written it as a question about joint densities rather than about likelihoods, if I'm right about the intended meaning of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is a probability density of a random variable $X$, then we have
$$
\Pr(X\in A) = \int\limits_A f(x)\, dx.
$$
Now suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with respective densities $f$ and $g.$ Then
\begin{align}
\Pr(X\in A\ \&\ Y\in B) & = \Pr(X\in A)\Pr(Y\in B) \\[10pt]
& = \int\limits_A f(x)\,dx \cdot \int\limits_B g(x)\, dx \\[10pt]
& = \int\limits_A f(x)\,dx \cdot \int\limits_B g(y)\, dy
\end{align}
because a bound variable can be freely re-named as long as the new name is not already taken. And you in an integral $\int_A \cdot\cdots \, dx$ with respect to $x,$, anything not depending on $x$ is a "constant", so you can write $\int_A f(x)\,dx \cdot 5 = \int_A f(x)\cdot5\, dx,$ etc., and accordingly we have
\begin{align}
& = \int\limits_A f(x) \left( \int\limits_B g(y)\, dy \right) \, dx \\[10pt]
\text{and then } & = \int\limits_A \left( \int\limits_B f(x)g(y) \, dy \right) \, dx \tag 1 \\[10pt]
& = \iint\limits_{A\times B} f(x) g(y) \, d(x,y) \text{ by Tonelli's theorem}. \tag 2
\end{align}
Now, what does this mean? The "double integral"
$$
\iint\limits_{A\times B} \cdots \, d(x,y)
$$
is an integral with respect to the $2$-dimensional measure in the plane, in which the measure of a region is its area. The "iterated integral"
$$
\int\limits_A \left( \int\limits_B \cdots\, dy \right) \, dx
$$
involves two integrals with respect to $1$-dimensional measure in the line, in which the measure of an integral is its length. Tonelli's theorem says that as long as the function getting integrated is everywhere non-negative, then the values of the iterated integral in line $(1)$ and the double integral in line $(2)$ are the same (regardless of whether the value is a finite number or $+\infty$). (There is also the related Fubini's theorem, which says that if the double integral of the absolute value of the function is finite, then iterated integral and the double integral are equal.)

So now we have
$$
\Pr(X\in A\ \&\ Y\in B) = \iint\limits_{A\times B} f(x) g(y) \, d(x,y).
$$
Therefore the function $(x,y) \mapsto f(x) g(y)$ behaves like the density function of the random pair $(X,Y),$ at least as far as product sets like $A\times B$ are concerned. Does it still behave like the density of $(X,Y)$ if instead we integrate over, for example a disk in the plane? Here one would need to show that if it works for things like $A\times B,$ then it also works for things like a disk and for all other "measurable sets" in the plane. That's a fairly hairy argument, but if you've got that, then we're done.

Comment: No wonder the textbooks alway seem gloss over this point.

Comment: @rhody : There's also a heuristic argument, about like this: Thing of $dx$ and $y$ as infinitely small increments of $x$ and $y.$ Then $$ \Pr(x< X < x+dx\ \&\ y < Y < y+dy) = \big( f(x)\,dx\big)\big( g(y)\, dy\big) = f(x) g(y) \, d(x,y). $$ This sort of heuristic can be very useful even if it falls short of logical rigor. $\qquad$

Comment: @rhody : If you have any concerns about the comment about renaming bound variables, think about how it applies to this example: $$ \begin{align} & (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)(7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2) \\ {} \\ = {} & \left( \sum_{i=1}^3 i^2 \right)\left( \sum_{i=7}^9 i^2 \right) \\ {} \\ = {} & \left( \sum_{i=1}^3 i^2 \right)\left( \sum_{j=7}^9 j^2 \right) \quad \big( \text{re-naming a bound variable} \big) \\ {} \\ = {} & \sum_{i=1}^3 \left( i^2 \left( \sum_{j=7}^9 j^2 \right) \right) \\ {} \\ = {} & \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=7}^9 i^2 j^2 \end{align} $$

Comment: @rhody : $\quad \uparrow \quad$ I've made some corrections in the comment above since I first posted it, so look at it now. $\qquad$

Comment: I have been trying to think of it in terms of vertical slices, $f(x_i) \delta x_i$ of the pdf but hadn't got very far. I will need to study your arguments more closely.

Comment: I've gone over your algebra and it makes sense logically but I can't see how to connect it to the original question. The problem is I'm not sure how to interpret your final double integral. These are genuine questions, not trying to criticize or annoy you, and they may be clumsy and dumb and you're thinking why do I have to respond to idiots.

Comment: @rhody : The function of which it is an integral is the result of multiplying the "heights". And I showed that it behaves like a density as far as sets of the form $A\times B$ are concerned, i.e. integrating that function over that set yields the probability assigned to that set. If a function of $(x,y)$ behaves that way with respect to EVERY measurable set, then it is the sought density function.

Comment: @rhody : i.e., if one can show that for every measurable subset $C$ of the plane, one has $$ \Pr((X,Y)\in C) = \iint\limits_C h(x,y)\,d(x,y), $$then one has shown that $h$ is the probability density function of the random variable $(X,Y). \qquad$

Comment: Thank you for that, your answer has helped, I missed the bit about 'behaves like a density'. I looked at the other question which was suggested to be a duplicate but it didn't seem to help me.