Proof of the simplification of the likelihood function
There are many references that quote that under the assumption that $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$ are i.i.d., the likelihood function can be simplified as follows:
$$P(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n|\theta)=P(x_1|\theta)P(x_2|\theta)\ldots P(x_n|\theta)$$
Unfortunately, most references take this simplification as given without providing any proofs or explanation.
What is the proof behind the above simplification?

It's a basic fact about independence.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302198 for the same question, phrased a little more generally.

Thanks @whuber, wouldn't the given $\theta$, require additional proof?

Not at all, because the duplicate applies to the likelihood no matter what value $\theta$ might have.

Understood - would you like to provide the explanation as an answer or do you believe the question should be closed?
